# Space before y axis

Tags: matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# data
data = {"yLabels": ["                         Ticklabel1", "Ticklabel2", "Ticklabel3"], "Total":[10.3, 7.5, 3.6]}
dataFrame  = pd.DataFrame(data = data);

# figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(10,3))
fig.patch.set_facecolor('#bbffbb')

# Plot
dataFrame.plot.barh(x='yLabels', y='Total', title="", figsize=(10,3), ax=ax)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.yaxis.set_label_text(None);

plt.show();
```

Results in:

[image: Width of red arrow]

Question: Is it possible to exactly specify the width before the y-axis (see red arrow), independent of the lenght of the ticklabels, and without affecting the total width (the width of the green area).

So, for example, if the width before the y label (the red arrow) increases, the width of the plot (the grey area) degreases. The total width (the green area) stays the same.

Comment: `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)` would fix the space for the red arrow to 20% of the figure width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *tricky* solution would be to make extra whitespaces in the ticklabels with [`set_ticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticklabels.html).

```
N = 0 # <- adjust here the pad

ax.yaxis.get_ticklocs()

ytlabels = [f"{' ' * N}{label.get_text()}"
            for label in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()]

ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(ytlabels)
```

Output :

`N = 0`

[image]

`N = 50`

[image]